# Add Numbered Pagination to My Custom WP Query

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I do have this code in my News Page Template

```
<?php $mcc_query = new WP_Query('showposts=3'); 
    while($mcc_query->have_posts()) : $mcc_query->the_post(); ?>

<div class="main-news-cont">
  <div class="news-feat fl"></div>
  <div class="news-content-cont fr">
    <div class="news-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?> ">
      <?php the_title( '<h2>', '</h2>' ); ?>
      </a></div>
    <div class="news-meta"><?php echo get_the_date('j F, Y'); ?>, <?php echo get_the_time(); ?> Written by <a href="">
      <?php the_author(); ?>
      </a></div>
    <div class="news-excerpt">
      <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?> " id="readmore-news">Read More</a> </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div>
<?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
```

I'm using the WP Navi Plugin, but it doesnt show any pagination in my News page.
What am i missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, actually wp_pagenavi(); uses global $wp_query variable to determine the pages and therefore show pagination.

but for custom query like yours may not work. but you can help it do this way.

```
<?php 
global $wp_query; 
$old_query=$wp_query; // backup $wp_query so we can roll it back later
?>
<?php $wp_query= new WP_Query('showposts=3'); // use $wp_query instead of your own variable so every other stuffs work as expected in the loop ?>
    <?php while($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
        <?php /* your post loop content */ ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_pagenavi(); // show the pagination pagination ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); wp_reset_query(); //roll back query vars to as per the request ?>
<?php $wp_query=$old_query; // revert back the $wp_query to as it was before ?>
```

Hope this helped!!

Comment: It did came out, but when i click page 2 or 3.. it doesnt go there

Comment: hmm.. so you need to do `$wp_query=new WP_Query('showposts=3&paged='.max(1,get_query_var('paged')));`

Comment: Thanks it did work, can you edit your answer and explain in details what and how it happened? I'm want to learn how. thanks!!

Comment: Yes.. actually wp_pagenavi() that you want to use actually uses $wp_query as its default global variable that wp uses everywhere and is inheritated from wp default query per the current url. so wp_pagenavi() is expected to work according to wp_query request variable. So if you however overwrite with your custom query, then it will work as expected. But make sure you revert it back to how it was as I used old_query var. Not sure if i am absolutely correct, but this way worked perfectly for me till date :)